# How to use generic file referencing location in Kivy?

Tags: python, path, kivy

As I have to submit all .py and .kv files to school, they required us to use generic file referencing location though cloud storage. My original path in .kv files is some personal directory path like this,

```
#: include /Users/goolite/Documents/FYP/app/homepage.kv
...
```

How to change them to generic file referencing location? Thank you so much!!

Comment: If your app class is named like "MyApp" , save the .kv fie in the same name in the same directory! Pyhton automatically checks for a .kv file with the same or startswith name as the app class

Comment: So I just need to save all stuff in the same directory. Then change the path to `#: include homepage.kv`?

Comment: you dont need the include statement too

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: did that work??